# Long running tasks with callbacks to activity or fragment

Tags: android, android-activity, android-asynctask, android-service

Question: What is the best practice for reporting progress/complete from long running task to an Activity? And what to do when the progress/complete report happens while the Activity is in the background/orientation changes?

Real life example: 
An Activity makes a network call getting data from a server (this could take 10+ sec).
When this network call is finished, the Activity should be notified and the Activity should show that the network call is finished.

This is easy to implement as long as the app stays open. My problem is, what to do if the network call is finished while the app is in the background (activity will miss any callbacks).

I have been looking at the following ways to do this, but I can not decide what to do:

- Service that spawns a thread where the network call is executed. The Service is bound to the Activity. On network call finish, Service callbacks to the Activity. If Activity is in background when the Service makes a callback (therefore the Activity misses the callback), should the Activity poll the Service for saved data?
- IntentService that broadcasts the data when network call is finished (what to do if Activity misses this broadcast because it is in background?)
- AsyncTask, but this is bad when Activity is in background etc.

How should I approach this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem using `HeadlessFragments` as its called. [This](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2013/04/retaining-objects-across-config-changes.html) blog post explains in detail how to implement it and the concerns you mentioned are handled by it.

EDIT:
For the questions in the comment:

1. To your specific question, about callbacks being lost when `Activity` is in the background, the answer is no. Being in "background" means that `Activity` is still alive. From the link I posted, the `callback`, which is the `Activity` itself, is removed when its detached from the `Activity` i.e when the `Activity` is `destroyed`. So, if your `Activity` is in the background and not `destroyed`, it'll still get the `callback` and do whatever you do in that `callback`. Although Android can kill Activities that are `paused`, in which case, your `Activity` will be `destroyed` and you won't get the `callback`. In such case, you can either save the data you get from server in a persistent storage, like `SQLite`, and prevent making another network call or make the network call when the `Activity` is created which will ensure that whenever the `Activity` is `created`, you'll have data to display (given of course, the call goes through).
2. The use of `Fragment` was specifically to handle the configuration change you mentioned in your question.  The running task is still being done by the `AsyncTask` and not by the `Fragment`. The `Fragment` only holds a reference to the object. So, I'd argue about it not being a "best practise".

Comment: Thanks for the link. I have two questions: 

What if the task completes while the activity is in the background. Then all callbacks will have been missed, right? How do I get the data that has been retrieved from the server while the activity was in the background?

It does not seem like a "best practice" to use a fragment for running tasks?

I definitely see the point in this approach though.

Edit: Should I store the data in the HeadlessFragment and then request the data from the fragment if "TaskHasFinished"?

Comment: @JonasJensen please see the edited answer for your questions.